# System test frameworks for scale testing on physical and virtual systems

Tags: testing, systems, control-framework

I'm searching for a framework for running system tests. The requirement are:

- Able to manage provisioning to multiple physical machine
- Able to manage provisioning to multiple virtual environments (AWS, Azure, etc)
- Able to run tests on a given machine be it physical or virtual.
- Not bound to a single language or platform. We wish to at least test against Linux, Windows at least.

Is there anything that meets those requirements?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Test Kitchen? Your requirements are huge and vague but it's probably your best bet.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. The product we want to test has components that span many platforms both physical and virtual and so we are searching for a framework that we can use to manage testing across those platforms.

Comment: When you get to something that complex, the chances of finding something perfect off-the-shelf drops asymptotically to zero.

Comment: I can't imagine we're the only ones who are having this issue so I figure it was worth asking. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: The problem is "this issue" in the general case is very different from your specific mix of tools and environments.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a software which is resource agnostic

- provision any resource type
- configure any resource type
- execute on any resource

I am biased but you can look at some [job schedulers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software). We are currently using ProActive from Activeeon which should answer your needs but other may have similar behaviors.